# GetScriptDescriptors() method for two .js files : strange unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, asp.net, custom-server-controls

My custom server-side ajax control implements  IScriptControl :

- GetScriptReferences
- GetScriptDescriptors

First method sends javascript files,second creates javascript objects based on some sended earlier .js files.

In my 'AssembleyInfo' file I added below lines and marked .js files in Properties explorer as 'Embedded resourece' :

```
    // this allows access to this files
    [assembly: WebResource("ProjectName.file1.js", "text/javascript")]

    [assembly: WebResource("ProjectName.file2.js", "text/javascript")]
```

Here is implementation of IScriptControl :

```
            public IEnumerable<ScriptReference>  
                GetScriptReferences()
            {
                yield return new ScriptReference("ProjectName.file1.js", this.GetType().Assembly.FullName);
                yield return new ScriptReference("ProjectName.file2.js", this.GetType().Assembly.FullName);
            }

            public IEnumerable<ScriptDescriptor>
                GetScriptDescriptors()
             {


                ScriptControlDescriptor descriptor = new ScriptControlDescriptor("ProjectName.file1", this.ClientID);
                //adding properties and events (I use "AnotherName" on the safe side to avoid potentional namespace problems           
                ScriptControlDescriptor descriptor2 = new ScriptControlDescriptor  ("AnotherName.file2", this.ClientID);
                //adding properties and events   

                yield return descriptor;
                yield return descriptor2;

            }
```

Here is parts of my .js files:

- first file

  ```
  Type.registerNamespace("ProjectName");

  ProjectName.file1 = function (element) {
  .......
  .......
  }
  ProjectName.file1.registerClass('ProjectName.file1', Sys.UI.Control);

  if (typeof (Sys) !== 'undefined')
      Sys.Application.notifyScriptLoaded();
  ```
- second file

  ```
  Type.registerNamespace("AnotherName");

  AnotherName.file2 = function (element) {
  ............
  ............
  }
  AnotherName.file2.registerClass('AnotherName.file2', Sys.UI.Control);

  if (typeof (Sys) !== 'undefined')
      Sys.Application.notifyScriptLoaded();
  ```

**WHY CREATES ONLY FIRST OBJECT?**

```
    yield return descriptor
```

**MY ASPX HAS JAVASCRIPT THAT MUST CREATE SECOND.**

IF I COMMENT ABOVE STATEMENT SECOND CREATES NORMALLY.

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, but is that some c# code i see there in those first 2 code blocks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have multiple control definitions registered for the same DOM element - you'll get a script error:

> Sys.InvalidOperationException: A control is already associated with the element.

You'll need to change one or both of your script classes to inherit `Sys.UI.Behavior` instead of `Sys.UI.Control`:

```
YourType.registerClass("YourType", Sys.UI.Control);
```

becomes:

```
YourType.registerClass("YourType", Sys.UI.Behavior);
```

You'll also need to replace the relevant `ScriptControlDescriptor` with a `ScriptBehaviorDescriptor`:

```
new ScriptControlDescriptor("YourType", ClientID);
```

becomes:

```
new ScriptBehaviorDescriptor("YourType", ClientID);
```

Have a look at the extender control walk-through on MSDN for information on creating script behaviors:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386403%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: I test MSDN example for several descriptors - all works fine.But in my case  ScriptBehaviorDescriptor doesnt solve my problem.I think that is I am not derived from ExtenderControl.But I dont want to do it.I dont need extender.Is there some way to return few descriptors,or I cant do that with control (only with behavior) ?

Comment: I've updated my answer - you can't have more than one `Sys.UI.Control` associated with an element. If you change the script class to inherit `Sys.UI.Behavior`, you can still use it from a `ScriptControl`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your problem stems from the fact that you use TWO returns

```
yield return descriptor;
yield return descriptor2;
```

First one does the return and then its over, you cant have a function that has two returns like that. Try creating IEnumerable collection, put the descriptors inside, then return the entire thing.

```
List<ScriptDescriptor> descList = new List<ScriptDescriptor>();
descList.add(descriptor);
descList.add(descriptor2);
return descList;
```

Comment: You can't have two `return` statements in a method, but you *can* have two `yield return` statements in an iterator.